# Ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python, словари

Пытаюсь считать данные, используя pymavlink. При компиляции появляется ошибка `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'`. Я не могу понять, почему в данном случае `master.recv_msg()` возвращает None.

```
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil

master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('tcp:000.000.000.0:0000')

def read_values():
    
    try:
        msg = master.recv_msg().to_dict()
        #print(msg)
        while True:
            Battery_current = (msg['current_battery']*2)/100
            Battery_voltage=((msg['voltages'])[0])/1000
            Battery_SOC=((msg['voltages'])[9])/10
            print("Battery current = "+str(Battery_current)+" Battery voltage = "+str(Battery_voltage)+" SOC = "+str(Battery_SOC))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program stopped")

read_values()
```

Если я делаю все то же самое, но без функции, а только с помощью while, то все работает:

```
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil


master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('tcp:000.000.000.0:0000')

while True:
    try:
        msg = master.recv_msg().to_dict()
        #print(msg)
        if msg['mavpackettype'] == 'BATTERY_STATUS':
            Battery_current = (msg['current_battery']*2)/100
            Battery_voltage=((msg['voltages'])[0])/1000
            Battery_SOC=((msg['voltages'])[9])/10
            #print("Battery current = "+str(Battery_current)+" Battery voltage = "+str(Battery_voltage)+" SOC = "+str(Battery_SOC))
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы привели правильный код, то возможно во втором случае у вас тоже периодически выпадает тот же эксепшен, но вы его просто не видите из-за того, что просто пропускаете все ошибки:

```
except:
    pass
```

В первом же куске кода вы ловите только прерывание с клавиатуры, поэтому видите остальные исключения:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Program stopped")
```

Документации толком нагуглить не удалось, но судя по фрагментам кода, которые я видел, цикл работы должен быть такой:

```
while True:
    try:
        msg = master.recv_msg()
        if msg: # проверка, что сообщение не пустое
            print(msg)
            # дальнейшая работа с msg
    except:
        pass # не очень хорошо, лучше тут печатать ошибку хотя бы
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: В первом случае тоже добавил `except:pass`, ошибка сама пропала, но когда пытаюсь сделать `print(msg)` то возвращается None

Comment: @AlexTsp Вот и проверяйте, что там не пусто сначала. Судя по всему это нужно делать. Добавил кусок кода

Answer (score 0):

Может В функции он принимает master за локальную переменеую?

Поставь в функции global master или передай его в качестве аргумента

Comment: Нет, пока в саму глобальную переменную ничего не записывается, она нормально должна восприниматься в функции. Можно вызывать её методы, это допустимо.